# Importing a CMake project into CodeLite

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, codelite

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to import an existing cmake project into the CodeLite IDE?

This is a C++ project and I have all of the .c and .h files. I have the CMake lists and what not for the project too.

I am running on Ubuntu 16.04 with CodeLite 11.0.4.

If CodeLite is not able to do this, then is there an IDE that can import a CMake project?

Comment: Have you tried to [read the CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/)? Especially the section on [*generators*](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) which [extra generators list](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#extra-generators) includes [CodeLite](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/CodeLite.html).

Comment: Hello thank you for the reply. I am not sure if I understand your comment correctly in relation to the question? I looked through the link provided and it looks like that the documentation is lists some IDEs that can generate CMAKE files. I am kinda looking for a tutorial on how to import a CMAKE project into the CodeLite IDE. I have reason to believe that CodeLite can interface with CMAKE, I am not sure how though.

Comment: You can tell CMake to generate a CodeLite project from a set of `CMakeLists.txt` files.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that! Cool, thank you for that little piece of information! I will look into this. As always, if you could place that in as an answer, I will upvote it and if it works, accept as a solution

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Please submit this as an answer so that I can accept because I was able to get it to work using what you suggested

Comment: The eclipse CDT has better cmake integration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate a CodeLite workspace with cmake by using the **-G** option. First, look up all available CodeLite generators by doing

```
cmake --help
```

Keep in mind that not all might work for you, depending on your system configuration. Then use one of them as you like. For example, using Ninja you can do:

```
cmake -G "CodeLite - Ninja" /path
```

where `/path` is the directory where your **CMakeLists.txt** is located.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate Codelite workspace with cmake by:

```
cmake -G "Codelite - Unix MakeFiles" /path (where 'path' your CMakeFiles.txt is present)
```

For instance:

1. Generate Codelite workspace

   ```
   cmake -G "CodeLite - Unix Makefiles" **./**
   ```

   [image]
2. Codelite workspace is generated

   [image]
3. Open CodeLite and build project (P.S. do not forget to set up project appropriately (e.g. compiler / workspace settings)

   [image]

   [image]

Answer (score -1):

According to Some programmer dude, CMAKE is able to make a codeLite project. I have tested this with the version of CMAKE that you can install with `sudo apt-get install` in ubuntu 16.04. This works.